# Facebook Exception at the time of autoposting in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, exception

I am getting this exception sometimes at the time of autoposting some videos into facebook in my app **"Your message couldn't be sent because it includes content that other people on Facebook have reported as abusive."**

I'm not getting the exact issue can any one please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sounds like people are marking your auto posts as spam

Comment: no no .. i have made my post from my app as private only visible to me how can people know the thing n this cannot be the issue with two diferent accts i'll tried @WizKid

Comment: Did you find any solution , I am facing the same issue . Is this something related to the App created from facebook ?

Comment: it is not app side its automatically rectified for me Some days later, facebook side they are not allowing autoposting some times.. @Purva

Comment: do we need to notify facebook for same ?